Is there a way to use arrays in switch statement case (C)?
I'm doing a CS50 problem set where I have to make a game of scrabble basically two people write a word and each letter in the word gives certain amount of points. E.g. A gives one point and Z gives 10
I was trying to make the storing system using a switch statement and a couple of char arrays containing each letter and how many points it gives. E.g. array One stores letters that give one point and Two two points and so on
but I figured out I can't put arrays in x position the (case x:)
so i tried a few things and got this.
Is there a way to make this more efficient or should I go back to switch statements or what?
#include <cs50.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(void)
{
    //get the strings from the players and store them in a string data type
    string p1 = get_string("Player 1: ");
    string p2 = get_string("Player 2: ");
    //make score data types for each player
    int score1 = 0;
    int score2 = 0;
    char one[20] = {'a','A','e','E','i','I','l','L','n','N','o','O','r','R','s','S','t','T','u','U'};
    char two[4] = {'d','D','g','G'};
    char three[8] = {'b','B','c','C','m','M','p','P'};
    char four[10] = {'f','F','h','H','v','V','w','W','y','Y'};
    char five[2] = {'k','K'};
    char eight[4] = {'j','J','x','X'};
    char ten[4] = {'q','Q','z','Z'};
    int str = strlen(p1);
    for (int N = 0; N < str; N++)
    {
        if (p1[N] == one[0] || p1[N] == one[1] || p1[N] == one[2] || p1[N] == one[3] || p1[N] == one[4] || p1[N] == one[5] || p1[N] == one[6] || p1[N] == one[7] || p1[N] == one[8] || p1[N] == one[9] || p1[N] == one[10] || p1[N] == one[11] || p1[N] == one[12] || p1[N] == one[13] || p1[N] == one[14] || p1[N] == one[15] || p1[N] == one[16] || p1[N] == one[17] || p1[N] == one[18] || p1[N] == one[19])
        {
            score1++;
        } else if (p1[N] == two[0] || p1[N] == two[1] || p1[N] == two[2] || p1[N] == two[3])
        {
            score1 += 2;
        } else if (p1[N] == three[0] || p1[N] == three[1] || p1[N] == three[2] || p1[N] == three[3] || p1[N] == three[4] || p1[N] == three[5] || p1[N] == three[6] || p1[N] == three[7])
        { 
            score1 += 3;
        }
    }
}


You should probably also check the strings to ensure they are just letters (no digits or other special characters) and give an appropriate error if they are not.

Fun fact: Legal Scrabble words exclude "words" that include uppercase (eg: "NASA", or "Mary", or "Scrabble", etc.)... and, yet, every Scrabble game I've seen uses tiles printed with only uppercase characters... It's a worry...

@user26580059: you can accept an answer by clicking on the grey checkmark below its score.

I think @TangentiallyPerpedicular is right to suggest a lookup table, but memory is cheap, so rather than make your array have 26 elements and do math to convert a character to an index, make it larger and do the lookups right on the ASCII value of each character.
Designated initializers make the initialization quite straightforward.
int main() {
    int char_vals[256] = {
        ['A'] = 1, ['E'] = 1, ['I'] = 1,
        ['L'] = 1, ['N'] = 1, ['O'] = 1,
        ['R'] = 1, ['S'] = 1, ['T'] = 1,
        ['U'] = 1,
        ['D'] = 2, ['G'] = 2,
        ['B'] = 3, ['C'] = 3, ['M'] = 3,
        ['P'] = 3,
        ['F'] = 4, ['H'] = 4, ['V'] = 4,
        ['W'] = 4, ['Y'] = 4,
        ['K'] = 5,
        ['J'] = 8, ['X'] = 8,
        ['Q'] = 10, ['Z'] = 10
    };

    // ...
}

Alternatively when you want to check for membership in an array, you should be using a loop.
    char one[20] = {'a', 'A', 'e', 'E', 'i', 'I', 'l', 'L', 'n', 'N', 'o', 'O', 'r', 'R', 's', 'S', 't', 'T', 'u', 'U'};

    for (size_t N = 0; N < str; N++)
        int worth_one = 0;
        for (size_t i = 0; i < sizeof(one); i++) {
            if (str[N] == one[i]) {
                worth_one = 1;
                break;
            }
        }

        if (worth_one) {
            score1++;
            continue;
        }

        // Repeat for two, three, four, etc.
    }

Beware that such an approach has linear runtime complexity while the lookup table has constant runtime complexity.

You should use int char_vals[128] = {... to insure that your lookup table can work for any ASCII character.  You can also put in initializers for lower case letters as well (['a'] = 1).  If want to minimize space, you could use int char_vals[32] = { ['A'&31] = 1,... and use char_vals[p[i]&31] to get the value of any specific character.  This avoid the need for separate upper/lower case as the map to the same 5 bits for ASCII.

It was pointed out to me in a comment that the world is not ASCII (IBM EBCDIC mainframes are still used). If you trust your text encoding and really want to hack bits, maybe define a macro to make it clear what's happening.

Two things: str is used inconsistently. Needs attention. And, sizeof(one[0]) is, by definition, 1 (because it's a char datatype). A tiny simplification. Cheers!

Why would you not do one = "AEILNORSTU"; ... if (strchr(one, toupper(str[N])) != NULL) { score1++; continue } ...?

In addition to multiple correct solutions using arrays, you can also use a switch statement if that is what you are expected to:
#include <cs50.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int compute_score(const char *word) {
    int score = 0;
    for (size_t i = 0; word[i]; i++) {
        unsigned char uc = word[i];  // always use unsigned char with ctype macros
        switch (toupper(uc)) {
          case ' ':    // Accept space as wildcard. No points.
            break;
          case 'A':
          case 'E':
          case 'I':
          case 'L':
          case 'N':
          case 'O':
          case 'R':
          case 'S':
          case 'T':
          case 'U':
            score += 1;
            break;
          case 'D':
          case 'G':
            score += 2;
            break;
          case 'B':
          case 'C':
          case 'M':
          case 'P':
            score += 3;
            break;
          case 'F':
          case 'H':
          case 'V':
          case 'W':
          case 'Y':
            score += 4;
            break;
          case 'K':
            score += 5;
            break;
          case 'J':
          case 'X':
            score += 8;
            break;
          case 'Q':
          case 'Z':
            score += 10;
            break;
          default:
            printf("not a letter: `%c`\n", uc);
            return -1;
        }
    }
    return score;
}

int main(void) {
    //get the strings from the players and store them in a string data type
    string p1 = get_string("Player 1: ");
    string p2 = get_string("Player 2: ");
    //compute the player scores
    int score1 = compute_score(p1);
    int score2 = compute_score(p2);
    printf("Player 1 got %d points for '%s'\n", score1, p1);
    printf("Player 2 got %d points for '%s'\n", score2, p2);
    return 0;
}


My C isn't up to this any more, but here's what you do:

create a 26 element array with each element containing the score for the corresponding letter A - Z. (Something like int letters[26]={1,3,3,2,1 etc.}
Iterate over the word.
For each letter convert to upper case and get the ASCII value of the letter.
Deduct 65 (ASCII A is 65). If your value here is negative or in
excess of 25(Z) the character is invalid.
Use the value as an offset into the array of letter scores and add the result to the word score.

This solution requires one simple array, a little straightforward manipulation of the character values, and no complicated boolean expressions.

Let the compiler do the math for you, since characters are numbers. For char c, compute the index by i = c - 'A'. If i > 'Z' then try converting to lower case with i -= ('a' - 'A'). At that point if i < 'A' or i > 'Z' then it's invalid and can be skipped.

@JohnBayko Neat. Last time I wrote C was about 40 years ago.

Yes, on using - 'A' to convert an upper-case letter to a zero-based index into the alphabet.  No on the other operations: use #include <ctype.h>, isalpha() and toupper().  They're provided by the C standard.

True, in EBCDIC upper case characters have higher values, ASCII they are lower values (although minus 'a' - 'A' still works), and they are not contiguous so simple less or greater than 'A' or 'Z' doesn't work. But my point was just that character literals are integers, not about correctness overall.

Also I got some of the math a little wrong anyway. I'll leave it as an exercise for the reader.

You need a function to validate the strings so you don't write the same code out twice. You can use arrays in switch statements, but probably not the way you're thinking of doing it. And an array solution is much simpler.
Here's a simple version of working code.  It uses Standard C I/O with fgets() rather than the get_string() preferred by CS50, but that can easily be fixed. The assignments using strcspn() are one way to zap the newline at the end of a line.
The function score() validates the data — non-letters are rejected and the player scores zero.
It converts the letter to upper-case and subtracts 'A' to convert it to a zero-based index into the array letters.  This is added to the score and when the string is complete, the score is returned.
The main() function reads the two players words, removes the trailing newline that fgets() leaves behind, and calls the score() function to establish the score.  It then prints the two scores.
#include <ctype.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

/* Assuming a codeset where the letter codes are contiguous (unlike EBCDIC) */
enum { BUFFER_SIZE = 128 };

static int score(const char *player, const char *word)
{
    static const char letters[] =
    {
        1, 3, 3,  2, 1, 4, 2, 4, 1, 8, 5, 1,  3,  /* A-M */
        1, 1, 3, 10, 1, 1, 1, 1, 4, 4, 8, 4, 10,  /* N-Z */
    };
    int score = 0;
    for (int i = 0; word[i] != '\0'; i++)
    {
        unsigned char uc = word[i];
        if (!isalpha(uc))
        {
            fprintf(stderr, "Invalid character '%c' in %s's word '%s'\n", uc, player, word);
            return 0;
        }
        uc = toupper(uc) - 'A';
        score += letters[uc];
    }
    return score;
}

int main(void)
{
    char p1[BUFFER_SIZE];
    char p2[BUFFER_SIZE];

    if (printf("Player 1: ") < 0 || fgets(p1, sizeof(p1), stdin) == NULL ||
        printf("Player 2: ") < 0 || fgets(p2, sizeof(p2), stdin) == NULL)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "failed to read data\n");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    p1[strcspn(p1, "\n")] = '\0';
    p2[strcspn(p2, "\n")] = '\0';

    int s1 = score("Player 1", p1);
    int s2 = score("Player 2", p2);

    printf("Player 1 scored %d with '%s'\n", s1, p1);
    printf("Player 2 scored %d with '%s'\n", s2, p2);

    return 0;
}

Example run:
Player 1: quizzical
Player 2: zoomjockey
Player 1 scored 38 with 'quizzical'
Player 2 scored 37 with 'zoomjockey'

You could devise a system so that you could initialize the array with letter names to identify the values.  You'd probably forgo the conversion to an index 0..25 and use the raw upper-case letter to index into the array.  This code reverts to using the CS50 function, get_string().
#include "cs50.h"
#include <ctype.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

static int score(const char *player, const char *word)
{
    static const char letters[] =
    {
        ['A'] = 1,  ['B'] = 3,  ['C'] = 3, ['D'] = 2,
        ['E'] = 1,  ['F'] = 4,  ['G'] = 2, ['H'] = 4,
        ['I'] = 1,  ['J'] = 8,  ['K'] = 5, ['L'] = 1,
        ['M'] = 3,  ['N'] = 1,  ['O'] = 1, ['P'] = 3,
        ['Q'] = 10, ['R'] = 1,  ['S'] = 1, ['T'] = 1,
        ['U'] = 1,  ['V'] = 4,  ['W'] = 4, ['X'] = 8,
        ['Y'] = 4,  ['Z'] = 10,
    };
    int score = 0;
    for (int i = 0; word[i] != '\0'; i++)
    {
        unsigned char uc = word[i];
        if (!isalpha(uc))
        {
            fprintf(stderr, "Invalid character '%c' in %s's word '%s'\n", uc, player, word);
            return 0;
        }
        uc = toupper(uc);
        score += letters[uc];
    }
    return score;
}

int main(void)
{
    string p1;
    string p2;
    if ((p1 = get_string("Player 1: ")) == NULL ||
        (p2 = get_string("Player 2: ")) == NULL)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "EOF or error on input\n");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    int s1 = score("Player 1", p1);
    int s2 = score("Player 2", p2);

    printf("Player 1 scored %d with '%s'\n", s1, p1);
    printf("Player 2 scored %d with '%s'\n", s2, p2);

    return 0;
}

This produces the same result for the same input data.  Note that this does not assume that the letters are contiguous in the code set, so it is arguably a better solution, but the array used is bigger.

Trivial mod: allow LF through the filter. Eliminates need for strcspn() that might be a bit advanced for a raw beginner at this stage. "Look up" will evaluate to zero (a low value control code), or could be made explicit with ['\n'] = 0, if thought necessary...

@Fe2O3: yes, but when the code uses the CS50 header and the get_string() function, the newline will be stripped off by the library code.  I was too lazy to build with my (probably somewhat old) cs50.h and libcs50.a, hence the use of pure C.  But the OP would simply replace that section of my code with the CS50 'official' functions.

@Fe2O3 — Hmmm: 'probably somewhat ancient' is putting it politely. It turned out that the library I had on hand was built in 2017 for an Intel MacBook Pro. I'm now using an M2 MacBook Pro. I needed to do some updating!  Having done so, I have revised the second program to use the CS50 library.  The input is considerably simpler, though a good error reporting package would improve things.

It is somewhat confusing to use static const char letters[]: the array elements are not letters, not even characters, they are integer scores. You could use static const unsigned char letter_score[] or simply static const int scores[] for clarity.

@JonathanLeffler :-) Better (for a CS50 student.) Nice... Next on my list of silly suggestions is to tally character instances and award "quizzical" only 28 pts. The second 'z' must have been a "blank Scrabble tile worth 0 pts". (Or, is this level of compliance only available in "The Deluxe Edition"? :-) Cheers!

@JonathanLeffler My bad... Just realised that "echoing" each word back to the output wouldn't be nice if the LF were still there... Please accept my apologies... Cheers! :-)

@Fe2O3: There were no signs in the question of limiting the occurrences of letters to the count in a Scrabble set.  Or, indeed, of limiting the input string to the size of a Scrabble board.  Nor was there anything to do with double-letter or triple-word scores, etc.  That's definitely the deluxe edition.

@JonathanLeffler AND, the Ultra Deluxe Edition also comes with a dictionary to prevent "NASA" or "UNESCO" as words requiring uppercase (like acronyms or proper names) are forbidden... Just having some fun... Cheers! :-)

If I were writing it from scratch, I'd probably do what @TangentiallyPerpendicular says but if you want to keep your basic logic:
Update your one, two, etc arrays to be strings like:
char one[] = "aAeEiIlLnNoOrRsStTuU";

and replace your long winded comparison with strchr:
if( strchr(one,p1[N])  )
{
    score1++;

you are searching for one character p1[N] in the array, one.  If you find it (strchr returns non-NULL (aka, non-zero, true), you have a string in the array.
To tidy up your search strings, use tolower in the search.  You'll have to
#include <ctype.h>

The updated one string would read:
char one[]="aeilnorstu";

with,
if( strchr(one,tolower(p1[N]) )
{
    score1++;


That feels clumsy.

@JonathanLeffler As I said, if I were writing it from scratch,  I would not implement it that way but the guy is learning C and I thought seeing that construct would be helpful.  I used C for years before it occurred to me that the int you are searching for does not have to be a constant and the string does not have to be a variable.


Is there a way to make this more efficient or should I go back to switch statements or what?

A table look-up is an efficient alterative.
The letters A-Z are very commonly sequential in their encoding, but C does not specify that.  By using an array, code does not need that property.
Sequential encoding is less likely with non-English character sets.  Let's consider initial steps toward supporting other character based languages.  Arrays will support that.
We will leave UTF8 for later.
IMO, int compute_score(const char *word) should also detect invalid input.
The is easy with an array.  By making the array cover all unsigned char values, we can readily detect bad input.
//  Consider some test in case we are on some unicorn compiler with high bits/char.
static_assert(CHAR_BIT < 10, "Unusually large bits per char");

int compute_score(const char *word) {
  // Since each letter score is a small value, 
  // might as well use a narrow type that matches the sign-ness of the score.
  static const signed char letter_value[UCHAR_MAX + 1] = {
     ['A'] = 1, ['B'] = 3, ['C'] = 3, ['D'] = 2, ['E'] = 1, // 21 more.
     ['a'] = 1, ['b'] = 3, ['c'] = 3, ['d'] = 2, ['e'] = 1, // 21 more.
     // All the other elements will have a value of 0.
  }
  score = 0;
  while (*word) {
    // Use a positive index as `char` may be signed.
    unsigned char uc = *word;
    int letter_score = letter_value[uc];
    if (letter_score == 0 && uc != ' ') {
      return -1; // Error
    }
    score += letter_score;
    word++;
  }
  return score;
}


  

